# SQL server database merging two columns?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table emp as follows:

```
empid  empname homephone  homeadd   workphone workadd
1      ron     209999000  1234st    222222    unit-20c
2      dd      2222333    unit56c   3444      bloor
```

I would like to create a temp table as follows:

```
empid  empname phone      add
1      ron     209999000  1234st
1      ron     222222     unit-20c
2      dd      2222333    unit56c
2      dd      3444       bloor
```

I would like to merge homephone and workphone under column phone and merge homeadd and workadd under column add. Anyone knows query for this?

Comment: do you only have two columns for phone, and two columns for address? or more? exact number, or unknown number? Basically, you want a 'reverse pivot'?

Comment: I have only two columns of phone and two columns of address

Comment: Ok - so thats easy - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a union to get them all merged, if you know the number of columns you want to 'merge'

```
select empID, empName, Homephone, Homeaddr from temptable
union
select empID, empName, WorkPhone, WorkAddr from temptable
union
select empID, empName, ExtraPhone, ExtraAddress from temptable
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge how? There's coalesce() and concat() - coalesce will return the first non-null argument, and concat will return all its fields as a single string. What do you want? The first address/phone found, or ALL the phones/addresses?

---

ok, thinking about it:

```
select empid, empname, homephone as phone, homeadd as add
from yourtable

union

select empid, empname, workphone as phone, workadd as add
from yourtable
```

not pretty, but it'll return what you want.

Comment: I want all the phone and addresses found.

Comment: He basically wants a 'reverse pivot' I think, making all the rows into a single column.

Comment: Concat() will merge two columns in for example phone is 2345 and address is ddff then after using cocat function the result would be 2345dff. But i dont want this I want rows as I have mentioned above.